# What is linkify's default link color?

Tags: android, linkify

When you do, for example,

```
Linkify.addLinks(mTextView, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
```

what colour does Linkify use?  It's not obviously in android.graphics.Color.

I have a few long paragraphs of stuff I just want standard links in, and one I need to do stuff with myself that I'd like to look the same, but I can't work out what colour to set it to.  I could just recolour all the others, but that seems a very long way around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default style uses `#05c5cf`, and the inverse style (I'm guessing this is for the light theme) uses `#0000EE` (at least in platform versions up to 2.2). No guarantees it stays that way, though, but I don't anticipate they'll change that (but who can really tell).

Comment: Neither of those match for me; it looks more like #5858F8.  Are they overlaid on the original colour somehow (eg, using something like PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)?

Comment: Ah: the dark theme color changed between versions: try `#5c5cff` for dark themes. Light themes are still `#0000ee`.

Comment: Yep, that's it, thank you -- which, yay!, but also that means it changes between versions, so I can't guarantee a match anyway.  Rats! >:(

Comment: Actually, what you want is `android.R.color.link_text_dark` and `android.R.color.link_text_light` and you should be able to match to version.

Comment: Those don't appear to exist for me.  Eclipse says it can't find them.

Comment: Odd. Those do appear to be platform-private. Try `android.R.attr.textColorLink` and see if that works: it's bound to the underlying theme so that SHOULD pick the right one.

Comment: getResources().getColor(android.R.attr.textColorLink) throws Resources$NotFoundException with message Resource ID #0x101009b.

Comment: Really odd: what Android revision are you building against? `getResources().getColor(android.R.attr.textColorLink);` and `devicelist.setTextColor(android.R.attr.textColorLink);` work fine for me when building against Android 2.0, and as far as I can tell the same attribute exists in Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 12):

```
Textview.getLinkTextColors().getDefaultColor()
```

Comment: will this return the hex color? If not, how can I?

Comment: @MatheusJardimB, it return hex color. please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html#getDefaultColor()

Answer (score 5):

By default, the links use `android:textColorLink` defined in the theme.